# How do I use this thing in Java / eclipse? (★)

Tags: java, eclipse, character

I am using an API, and can access it by secific URL-Request. However it almost always contains this thing (★), and I'm trying to add it whenever I need it.

But if I do it in eclipse, and sysout it, all I get is a "?".

Any ideas?

Comment: Your console's character set likely doesn't support that character.

Comment: You need to specify an encoding that matches your console and supports that character (UTF-8 would work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on your project and select properties
2. Select Resource -> Text file encoding
3. Change it to Other UTF-8

Then Run the program
[image]